# what algorithm for rules mining in itemsets

Tags: algorithm

I have following data, every entry contains an itemset and to which      class it belongs to (positive or negative).

What algorithm I can use to find out that what combination of items    indicate positive or negative?

In the following case, I want to find out that (B, C) indicate positive and    (D, E) indicate negative.

**B, C,** A -> positive

**B, C,** D -> positive

**B, C,** E -> positive

B, **D, E** -> negative

C, **D, E** -> negative

A, **D, E** -> negative

result: (B, C) indicate positive, (D, E) indicate negative.

I've tried frequent itemsets and apriori, result is not good, is there any other possible method?

Comment: Would you mind including your code and some **toy** input/output as expected/produced by such code?

Comment: its not clear to me but its seem you are looking for one of these data sctructure. `Unit<A>
Pair<A,B>
Triplet<A,B,C>
Quartet<A,B,C,D>
... `

Answer (score 0):

One typical algorithm could be mapping each pair of `items` in each record (`itemset`) into its `positive` or `negative` class and then count the number of mappings to either `positive` nor `negative` classes and compare the results to know which number is greater. That's the class you are looking for each pair.

It's very costly especially when your `itemsets` have large number of items reside in so, generally, you need some sort of data structures to store and retrieve data in fast and efficient way.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what apriori does.